# how to unit test an angular.js service call using jasmine.js

Tags: json, angularjs, jasmine

**It is a bit difficult for me to figure out the examples since I am a beginner could someone please help.**

This is my code simple anjular.js service call

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var mycontroller =  app.controller('Myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("service.json")/*the json that i pass*/
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
```

**I want to test this code using jasmine. What is the procedure and the code to do it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use httpBackend mock service that will help to test your service.

Example-

```
describe('Myctrl', function() {

   var $httpBackend, scope, createController, authRequestHandler;

   // Set up the module
   beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

   beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

     // Set up the mock http service responses

     $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

     // backend definition common for all tests

     authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'service.json')
                            .respond(true);

     // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)

     $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

     // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
     var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');


     createController = function() {

       return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : scope});

     };

   })

);


   afterEach(function() {

     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();

     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();


   });

   it('should fetch authentication token', function() {

     $httpBackend.expectGET('service.json');

     var controller = createController();

     expect(scope.names).toBe(true); 

     $httpBackend.flush();

   });


});
```

Comment: you need to configure karma first that will load your all js files.

Comment: i finished load karma but still i get an declaration exception error what is the issue

Comment: i resolved the problem of declaration exception now am getting the error msg saying " Cannot read property 'expectGET' of undefined" this and this error "Failed to instantiate module myApp "

Comment: no actually on the browser now am only getting the " Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Comment: hi now i am getting a error called  "Cannot read property 'module' of undefined"